# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException:Property not found on type java.io.File in primefaces download

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, download, myfaces

I am using Primefaces 3.2 and developing the file download functionality and I am getting list of file names from my local which i wanted to display them in jsf datatable with clickable option(h:commandlink).

When I excute my Code I am getting following exception.

> javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /faces/fileDownload.xhtml at line
>   33 and column 115 value="#{x.fileName}": Property 'fileName' not found
>   on type java.io.File

My Code looks like this Java File

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import org.primefaces.model.DefaultStreamedContent;
import org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent;

@ManagedBean(name="fileDownloadController")
@SessionScoped
public class FileDownloadController {

    private StreamedContent file;
    private List<File>  listfiles=new ArrayList<File>();
    private String fileName;

    public FileDownloadController() {        
        File filestream=new File("C:/temp.pdf");
        InputStream stream=null;
        try {
            stream = new FileInputStream(filestream);
        file = new DefaultStreamedContent(stream, "application/pdf", "temp.pdf");
        stream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public List<File> getListfiles() {
        File folder = new File("c:\\");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        listfiles=Arrays.asList(listOfFiles);
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<listfiles.size();i++){
       System.out.println("The List of file are"+listfiles.get(i));
       listfiles.get(i);
        }
        return listfiles;
    }

    public void setListfiles(List<File> listfiles) {
        this.listfiles = listfiles;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        getListfiles();
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public StreamedContent getFile() {
        return this. file;
    }
}
```

My XHTML looks like this.

```
<h:form id="form">  
 <h:dataTable value="#{fileDownloadController.listfiles}" var="x" 
              bgcolor="#F1F1F1" border="10" cellpadding="5" 
              cellspacing="3" first="0" rows="4" width="50%" 
              summary="This is a JSF code to create dataTable.">
              <h:column>
                <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="File Names"></h:outputText>
                </f:facet>
                <h:commandLink value="#{x.fileName}" onclick="PrimeFaces.monitorDownload(showStatus, hideStatus)">
                        <p:fileDownload value="#{fileDownloadController.file}" />
                </h:commandLink>
             </h:column>
               </h:dataTable> 
</h:form>
```

I am not able to figure out where i went Wrong.Please help me.

Comment: check this  solution ; 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822758/export-to-excel-jsf-and-primefaces/12526625#12526625

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you come to using `#{x.fileName}`? Look carefully in [the javadoc of the `java.io.File` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html). Right, there's no such method like `getFileName()`. That's *exactly* what the exception is trying to tell you.

> value="#{x.fileName}": Property 'fileName' not found on type java.io.File

Most likely you meant to use the [`getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29) method instead.

```
#{x.name}
```

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, your code would be more self-documenting if you used `var="file"` instead of the nonsensicial `var="x"`.

Comment: @BalusC.........I tried with other names otherthan fileName i didn't work.Magically with your answer it's working.You Rock Man....I am big fan of you and u r answers...

Comment: @BalusC..my filenames will as shown in above table.When User Clicks on the file I want to pass that file name to the FileDownloadController() method.I am passing it inside the <p:download>.It's not working.When I pass parameter to filedownloadController(string name) I am getting InstantationException.If i change the method name it's not working. Please help here.

Comment: That's a different problem. Press `Ask Question` button on right top to ask a question about that.

Comment: Hey I have updated above content in seperate question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12379416/issue-while-debugging-with-hdatatable-and-pdownload. Can you please take a look at that question.Thanks in advance