# How can I download a file which I have dynamically created on Apache TomCat Server?

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, primefaces, apache-poi

I created an ".xlsx" file (CustomerData.xlsx) by using "Apache POI".

The problem is that the file is created on my TomCat Server and I have to download it.

I tried the following code, in order to download the file:

```
HttpServletResponse response = null;

response.setContentType("xlsx");
response.setHeader(
    "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
    "attachment; filename=C:\CustomerData.xlsx");
try {
    workbook.write(response.getOutputStream());
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

but unfortunately, it does not seem to work.

In case you have any idea or suggestion, do not hesitate posting it.

Comment: As you tagged [primefaces], is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/7822758

Answer (score 1):

You mix content type and attachment information into a single header which cannot work.

Instead write

```
response.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=CustomerData.xlsx");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I applied the changes accordingly, but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: @StavrosVrakas "does not work" really is not much information.