# Exporting PDF on JSF doesn't export

Tags: jsf, jasper-reports

i got this problem when i try to export a datatable information to PDF, the method do all, but it doesn't download the PDF or even generate.

> Netbeans version: 8.2
>
> JSF: 2.2
>
> Primefaces: 5.3

```
Libraries used:
Jasperreports 6.3
poi 3.14
commons-beanutils-1.9.0
commons-collection-3.2.2
commons-digester-2.1
commons-logging-1.1.1
groovy-all-2.4.0
itext-2.1.7.js5
jaxp-ri
jcommon-1.0.23
jfreechart-1.0.19
```

And my method is:

```
public void exportpdf(OrdenRetiro or) throws JRException, IOException {
    conexion con = new conexion();
    Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ServletContext servleContext = (ServletContext) context.getExternalContext().getContext();
    parametros.put("RutaImagen", servleContext.getRealPath("/reportes/"));
    parametros.put("cod_ordenretiro", or.getCod_ordenretiro());
    
    String temperatura = or.getEs_temperado()==1?"ReporteFreezer.jasper":"ReporteNoFreezer.jasper";
    
    String dirReporte = servleContext.getRealPath("/reportes/"+temperatura);
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) context.getExternalContext().getResponse();
    response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Orden de Retiro"+or.getCod_ordenretiro()+".pdf");
    response.setContentType("application/pdf");

    JasperPrint impres = JasperFillManager.fillReport(dirReporte, parametros, con.getConnection());
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(impres, response.getOutputStream());
    context.responseComplete();            
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you try to generate report with simple test (export to file)?

Comment: I already got other project that has the same structure and the export works, you mean download the file on a folder directly?

Comment: You can create a simple console application to check the part of code related to the export report as pdf (with JasperReports API).

Comment: Please,  always, always, always post an [mcve]. What was wrong cannot be seen on your question.

Answer (score 1):

Got the solution.

When the method works but doesn't export is because the ajax on the xhtml. After doing some research got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7822758/export-to-excel-jsf-and-primefaces)

I make the puntual quote.

> The first problem is that the `<p:commandLink>` sends by default an Ajax
>   request. This request is fired by JavaScript code. However, JavaScript
>   can't do anything with a response which contains a file download. Due
>   to  security restrictions JavaScript can't spawn a Save As dialogue or
>   something. The response is basically totally ignored.
>
> You need to add `ajax="false"` to `<p:commandLink>` to turn ajax off so
>   that  the button fires a normal synchronous HTTP request, or you need
>   to  replace it by standard `<h:commandButton>`